# How to add other html file in thymeleaf，Is it OK ？

Tags: java, spring, jsp, thymeleaf

As you know，if we want to include other pages in jsp(most are header 、footer), we can write that in our jsp file：

```
<jsp:include page="/pages/common/header.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

if I want to  achieve the same function  that adding some html file in thymeleaf template , how can I do? Is it OK ？

Comment: Take a look at the docs

Answer (score 6):

No, you can’t include jsp files in thymeleaf. But you can include other thymeleaf pages. See how :

- [Difference between th:insert and th:replace (and th:include)](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#difference-between-thinsert-and-threplace-and-thinclude)